# Cannot find module 'bot/startup/StartupManager'

Tags: node.js, typescript, configuration, discord.js

I am trying to get into writing a discord bot, but I seem to have hit a snag with setting up typescript config / paths. Even though the compiler claims that it can find my file, the build command, npm run build, fails to find my module, and crashes.

my folder structure:

```
|src
  >|startup
    >|StartupManager.ts
|-app.ts
|-package.json
|-tsconfig.json
```

as there is a few moving parts here, I will outline what I have and the error I am trying to resolve:

tsconfig.json:

```
   ...
   "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "bot/*": [ "./src/*" ]
    }
   ...
```

app.ts (the **complaining file**)

```
import { StartupManager } from 'bot/startup/StartupManager';
export { StartupManager };

new StartupManager();
```

my build command:

```
"build": "tsc --build && tsc app.ts && node app.js",
```

In StartupManager:

```
import { ILogger, Logger } from 'bot/core/logger';

export class StartupManager {
...
}
```

Currently, I am working on Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. To re-iterate, My Text Editor shows that everything is fine, but the moment the build kicks off, I am greeted with:

```
    app.ts:1:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bot/startup/StartupManager'.

1 import { StartupManager } from 'bot/startup/StartupManager';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

Any advice anyone can lend me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) in the Typescript Handbook: *When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.*

So when you run `tsc app.ts` it does not know about the paths property set in `tsconfig.json`. Probably what you want to do is run only `tsc --build`, because that compiles the files including `app.ts`.

Regarding the `paths` property, it may still be necessary to install an additional package to run .js files that use the shorthand paths in the module imports. There are NPM packages like [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) that can help with this.